# How to test if the a model datetime is in the past?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model with a datetime (postgresql) and I want to test if the datetime has expired.

```
Content
-expired_at datetime
```

I have a method I am trying to write in my Content model:

```
def expired?
  ??? > expired_at
end
```

How should I be getting the current date and seeing if it greater than the current date and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `expired_at` as a Ruby DateTime, you can do something like this:

```
expiration = DateTime.now

if expired_at < expiration
  # not expired
else
  # meets or exceeds expiration time
end
```

If you're getting string data from the database, you can use:

```
DateTime.parse(my_date_string)
```

to create a DateTime object.